# Google Refine - pull out identical values in cell

Tags: data-manipulation, openrefine

I have data in a column that looks like this

```
["Lymore Cottages", "Lymore Cottages", "Lymore Cottages", "Lymore Cottages", "Lymore Cottages", "Lymor Cottages"]
```

Its essentially the same thing multiple times, but as these are entered by users they could be different. If you notice the last one has the e missing.

What I would like to do is create a new column with just the unique names in it. So the new column would just contain "Lymore Cottages, Lymor Cottages".

I believe this is possible with Google/open Refine. I tried clustering but this also clustered all the other rows with the same details rather than per cell. (I need this for each row regardless of if there are 20 other rows with the same data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a programming question, however a combination of splitting values in the cell, [removing the duplicates](http://googlerefine.blogspot.ca/2011/08/remove-duplicate.html) and then reassembling the contents might work.

There's probably an easier way to do this. Roughly, you could

*Split*

1. `Split multi-valued cells...` on the column
2. Remove the brackets and quotes with

   `value.replace('[', '').replace(']','').replace('"', '')`

*Remove duplicates*

3. Next, `Sort...` A-Z and `Reorder rows permanently`
4. `Blank down` on the column
5. Invoke the `Facet by blank` and select `True`
6. `Remove all matching rows` from `All` > `Edit rows`

*Reassemble*

7. On the column, `Transpose cells in rows into columns...`
8. Rebuild the field with brackets and quotes using

   `'['+ ' ' + value + ',' + ' ' + cells['Step 7 Field Name'].value + ' ' + ']'`